# Is it possible to force cvs commit to unchanged file?

Tags: cvs

I need to do empty checkin to cvs repository with special message. I mean, I don't really need to do any changes in file but I need to have commit with special message. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `-f` option.

```
cvs commit -f -m 'commit message' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much